# Why Netbeans Test RESTful sample program doesn't work?

Tags: rest, netbeans, sample

I've followed Netbeans Getting Started with RESTful Web Services example :

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html

It generated the project, but after I hit the "Test RESTful Web Services" selection, it displayed a page without left bar, like this :

[image]

I'm using Firefox 23.0, how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to deploy your Web Service first.

Then create a web Application.

Then test restful in that project by right clicking in RESTFUL WEB SERVICES package and choose test project.

And don`t forget to change the url open to the name of the test project.
For example:

http://localhost:8080/HappyHourServer/test-resbeans.html ---->   http://localhost:8080/TESTPROJECTNAMEEEEE/test-resbeans.html

And again don`t forget to deply your web services first!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a second web service to execute the first, like in the tutorial?

I had the same problem as you, but in my case, XAMPP was open. So I closed it, restarted the computer and followed the tutorial precisely.